# Display text as it is in html blockquote tag

Tags: html, css

I want to display text in `blockquote` tag

```html
<blockquote>
  This is my formatted text 
  This is the second line
</blockquote>
```

instead of `<pre>` tag.

```html
<pre>
  This is my formatted text
  This is the second line
</pre>
```

Because I couldn't change the `<blockquote>` to `<pre>` tag, but I want the text displayed in the same manner of using `<pre>` tag.

Are there any ways to do that in css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
blockquote {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sylvan, it works!